# ELK Docker - Kibana saved objects

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, kibana, dashboard

Does anyone know if it's possible to provide to kibana dockerized container saved objects (dashboards/ visualizations) during the startup of the container? I didn't notice any specific configuration for this on the elastic.co guides. Are there volumes on the container on which I can copy my .json files

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/awesome-inc/docker-elk-cyber/tree/cybersecurity/provisioner). The provisioner component should do what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and dashboards.

It creates a new index if the index doesn’t already exist.
kibana.index: ".kibana"